# Sum of numbers with exponent (N and P) in Python

Tags: python, math, formula

I need to make a Python program that asks for two numbers. N is the first number and P the second, the program must calculate the sum of the first N numbers raised to the value P, following this formula: 1^P + 2^P + 3^P + 4^P... + N^P

If I enter, for example, 3 and 5, it will do the following calculation: 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 = 276

This is what I currently have:

---

```
num1 = input('Enter first number: ')
num2 = input('Enter second number: ')
sum = float(num1) ** float(num2)
print('{0} raised to the power of {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
```

---

The problem is that I don't know how to make the program calculate that if the first number I enter is 3 and the second is 5, do 1 ^ 5 + 2 ^ 5 + 3 ^ 5, instead of just doing 3 ^ 5 (like my program does).
Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know how to create a loop for numbers 1 to N? Also, don't use `sum` as a variable name, because it is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: You have the `**` operator down right, but your question isn't totally clear. Perhaps you're looking for `range(1,3+1)`?

Comment: I just renamed my variables, thanks for the tip!
And about how to create a loop for numbers you mean using `if` together with `range ()`? I just started Python so I don't know if that is what you mean, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Gino Mempin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2745495/gino-mempin) said, loops are a good start.

```
def sum_exponents(end_num, exp):
    sum_ = 0
    for n in range(int(end_num)):
        n += 1
        sum_ += n ** float(exp)
    return sum_

num1 = input('Enter first number: ')
num2 = input('Enter second number: ')

print('{0} raised to the power of {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum_exponents(num1, num2)))
```

Comment: Why not: `for n in range(1, end_num + 1)`? And why do you convert to `float`?

Comment: It works perfectly! I will read more about loops for future programs, I am looking forward to learning Python.
Thank you very much to all!

Comment: @ekhumoro you're right `for n in range(1, int(end_num)+1)` would work equally well and do away with the `n += 1` on each iteration. I just left the op's cast w.r.t. `float`, but the input needed to be cast to some decimal at some point, otherwise the input would be evaluated as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Summing a list comprehension might do the trick:

```
p = 5
n = 3
sum((i+1) ** p for i in range(n)) # 276
```

`(i+1) ** p for i in range(n)` is a generator expression yielding (i+1)^p for each i in [0, n-1]. Calling `sum` on it returns the sum of those terms.

Comment: Two improvements to this: 1. the expression in `sum` can be a generator expression, doesn't need to be a list (remove the square brackets `[]` to remove the list comprehension). 2. It's clearer to change range instead of doing `(i+1)**p`; so `sum(n**P for n in range(1, N+1))`.

Comment: Agreed for the generator expression.
I somewhat agree for the `range` part in an everyday-life context but I think I'll keep it like this because it shows the behaviour when used with a single argument (exclusive upper bound in particular).
Also, PEP8 recommands upper case for constants only. We can debate if `p` and `n` are constants in this context, but as they are user input and not *strongly* defined constants, better keep lowercase IMO -it's more generic.